# Is smartcontract the only way to transfer ether in Ethereum network?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I am new to smartcontract and start writing some demo code in Solidity to work with Ropsten testing network. I see that I can use `send`/`transfer` method in the contract to transfer ether to other accounts. One question about it is that is contract the only way to transfer ether? Can I transfer ether without a contract?

I understand the concept of the `contract` but not sure whether it is a required thing in Ethereum. When I deploy a contract to the network, it will be sitting in a new block and all transactions generated from this contract are in the same block? Am I understand correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need a smart contract to sign or send a transaction. The transferring of ETH is built into the protocol. This can be accomplished by using libraries such as web3 or ethers if you're a developer. If you're not a developer, this can be accomplished by using tools such as Metamask.

Steps to send a transaction using ethers.js:

1. Instantiate your provider and signer using ethers.providers. and Signer.
2. Then sign a transaction using signer.signTransaction.
3. Use provider to send the transaction using provider.sendTransaction.

### References:

Ethers.js: https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/

web3.js: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.5.2/

metamask: https://metamask.io

Comment: Thanks for that. Yes I am a developer so that I can do that. If I deploy a contract and a few transactions are generated from the contract, does the contact block contains all the transactions?

Comment: @Joey Yi Zhao Yes, the smart contract's ethereum address will have a ledger of transactions executed listed just like any other ethereum address.

Comment: when you say `ledger`, does it mean a block in the Ethereum block chain? And all other transactions will be in the same block for the same ledger?

Comment: @JoeyYiZhao no, I meant the list of transactions related to your smart contract

Comment: so the ledger is in one block, and each transaction is in its own block?

Comment: @JoeyYiZhao no, a ledger is a tree immutable transactions, a block is a container, which includes a number transactions solved/confirmed by miners. I recommend rereading the ethereum documentation on these terms as they are very important concepts to understand before going deeper.